# Carregar Target do Iframe em uma nova Aba da Janela Principal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho uma página HTML que incorpora um código `iframe`, meu problema é que este código incorporado possui um formulário, que ao ser preenchido precisa ser aberto em uma nova aba, porém esta aba é aberta dentro da `div` onde o `iframe` está incorporado, eu preciso que esta nova aba seja aberta na janela principal.

### Importante

A página do iframe (página incorporada) está no mesmo domínio que a página principal e tenho acesso a ela, com isso eu posso colocar qualquer código jquery / javascript nela.

### Código Iframe:

```
<iframe src="http://siteexemplo.com.br/index2.php" scrolling="no" style=" width: 100%; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

Esta página do iframe contem um formulário com o seguinte HTML.

### HTML da página incorporada

```
<form class="form-signin" action="validacao.php" method="post" target="_self">
    <div style="width:60%; float:left">
        <input type="password" name="senha" id="inputPassword" style="height:47px" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" required>
    </div>
    <div style="width:39%; float:right">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" ><a style="color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none" >Visualizar</a></button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito de resolver isso é passar dentro do iframe a URL do que tu quer abrir na outra janela, o script pega o conteúdo da página e manda para o browser, então tu vai ter o conteúdo desejado na página, mas o endereço de um outro site, um exemplo em php pode ser:

http://yourdomain.com/getURL.php?url=http:www.google.com

referencia e mais explicações no texto original em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4583792/make-links-inside-an-iframe-open-in-a-new-window

Answer (score 0):

Cara, só pra ter certeza: você já experimentou mudar o target do form dentro do iframe para "_blank"? Ficaria assim:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="validacao.php" method="post" target="_blank">
  ...
</form>
```

---

Não funcionando, você pode capturar o envio do form com o evento `.onsubmit` ou `$().submit` e ir subindo até frame pai. Pra isso, pega o objeto `window.parent` que você vai usar pra abrir a nova aba. Ficaria algo como

```
window.parent.open("endereço do GET", "_blank")
```

Claro, como seu formulário é POST, talvez você precise deixar o formulário rodar o que ele precisa e passar um endereço GET temporário. No caso, como parece ser autenticação, a resposta do servidor chegaria pelo próprio iframe com o cookie da session, daí não teria problema incluir o código JS para executar somente na resposta do POST.